# Expected number of vertices a distance $k$ away in a random graph?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Given a random (undirected and unweighted) graph $G$ on $n$ vertices where each of the edges has equal and independent probability $p$ of existing (see [Erdős–Rényi model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model)). Fix some vertex $u\in G$. I want to know what is the expected number of vertices a distance $k$ away (where distance means the *shortest* distance). I can only figure out that we expect there to be $(n-1)p$ vertices a distance **1** away since each of the possible $(n-1)$ edges outgoing from $u$ have probability $p$ of existing, but I am having trouble generalizing from this local property. Maybe someone can handle the task or perhaps point me in the right direction via a paper?

If it makes it easier, assume that $G$ is connected (as it almost surely is as $n\rightarrow \infty$, which is the case I am interested about). As a subproblem of almost equal importance, I would in particular like to know what is the expected longest shortest distance from vertex $u$ and how many vertices are away from vertex $u$ at that distance (subproblem with the maximum possible $k$).

Note: (1) The graph does not have a bound on the degree of the vertex (there could be as many as $n-1$ adjacent vertices to $u$).

Comment: This problem has a lot of symmetry. I like to think of it as the complete graph with weights $p$ on the edges. I think the assumption that $G$ is connected is probabilistically speaking unnatural.

Comment: There are some easy $k$'s where you can compute explicitly ; for $k = n-1$, the only way that a vertex is at a distance $n-1$ is if you have a path graph ; for there must be a path of length $n-1$ from $u$ to some vertex $v$, hence you have a sequence
$$
u= u_0, e_1 = \{u_0,u_1\}, e_2 = \{u_1,u_2\}, \cdots , e_{n-1} = \{ u_{n-1},u_n\}, \quad u_n = v.
$$
Any edge outside the set $\{e_1,\cdots,e_{n-1}\}$ induces a path of length shorter than $n-1$ between $u$ and $v$, so you get a path graph. Computing the expectation becomes combinatorics in this case.

Comment: There are $\binom n2$ possible edges and $n-1$ of them must be in the graph, so the probability that a particular path happens is $p^{n-1} (1-p)^{\binom n2 - (n-1)}$ ; the number of possible paths is simply $n!$, i.e. the number of way to order $u_1,\cdots,u_n$. Your final answer is 
$$
n! p^{n-1} (1-p)^{\binom n2 - (n-1)} = n! p^k (1-p)^{\binom n2 - k}.
$$

Comment: Probabilistically speaking, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, then the probability of any vertex having an edge is $np$. I think this leads me to assume that the graph is connected.

Comment: Is the graph connected for all $n$ large enough with this linear bound? My graph theory is rusty but I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, I am not sure what you mean by "the probability that a particular path happens." I don't think this is equivalent to *a shortest path.* Shortest path may not be unique, but each shortest path leads to *the* shortest distance. My question is about how many vertices are there with the shortest distance $k$ away from any vertex.

Comment: @ijkilchenko $p=const$ is not the most interesting case. It is usually that $p=p(n)$, and in this case of course it is not a.a.s. that the graph is connected.

Comment: @ijkilchenko : I understand your point, but read my proof more carefully ; I am arguing that if there is a path of shortest length $n-1$ between $u$ and $v$, then the entire graph must be a path graph, because adding a single edge to the graph which is simply a path between $u$ and $v$ creates a path between $u$ and $v$ of length strictly smaller than $n-1$. In other words, if you have the graph 
$$
G = (\{u_0,u_1,u_2,u_3\}, \{ \{u_0,u_1\},\{u_1,u_2\},\{u_2,u_3\} \}),
$$
then there is a path of length $3$ between $u_0$ and $u_3$, but if you add an extra edge to this graph...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, oh okay. I see what you were continuing your proof which you started in the comment prior. Good special case, which might help in the general case. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. So now we have the cases $1$ and $n-1$, which gives us the numbers $(n-1)p$ and $n! p^{n-1} (1-p)^{\binom n2 - (n-1)}$. Interesting.

Comment: I don't think it would be too hard to obtain a formula for the expected number of vertices at distance at most $k$ (and then compute the $k$ case minus the $k-1$ case) by simply averaging the probability that a random path between $u$ and some vertex $v$ of length $k$ happens. Otherwise I don't see how this could be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\lambda=np$. Then the average distance $k$ between two randomly picked vertices from  the giant component is 
$$
k\sim \frac{\log n}{\log \lambda},
$$
given that the giant component exists ($\lambda>1$). A proof can be found in, e.g., Durrett's Random graph dynamics.

This result implies that the actual number for your first question is 
$$
\lambda^k.
$$
However, this only works if $pn\to\lambda<\infty$ when $n\to\infty$. What about the case $p=const$? Here is an exercise: Show that the diameter of the E-R random graph in this case is 2 a.a.s.

For the diameter (the largest among the shortest paths) the question is more subtle. A nice review is given in Complex Graphs and Networks bu Lu and Chung, and the answer depends on the parameters.

Comment: It's interesting that you get $\lambda^d$, because the cases $k=1$ and $k=n-1$ have a geometric random variable flavor.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva The results I state are asymptotic. (I changed my $d$ for $k$ as in the original question). I do not quite get what you calculate in the case "$k=n-1$".

Comment: @Artem, sorry, what is "a.a.s."?

Comment: @ijkilchenko Ups, apologies. Asymptotically almost surely. Another terminology is w.h.p. (with high probability). Probability of something going to 1 when $n\to\infty$

Comment: Are you having an issue with a specific detail in my proof? All I can do at this point is either answer your specific questions with regards to it or put more details in a separate answer.

Comment: @Photon Out of the top of my head: yes. You can find a non-rigorous discussion in Mark Newman's book *Networks: An introduction* and probably also some good references.